# Can't use prefixed URI after defining a prefix with Model.setNsPrefix()?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I don't understand why the following code behaves the way it does.  I'm trying to parse a DCAT document with Jena, and while it's not a deal breaker to use fully qualified URI's, I thought that setting the URI prefixes before attempting to access statements would allow me to use the shorthand notation.

For example, I set the dcat prefix, but I can't search the model this way using dcat:distribution.  Instead I have to use the fully qualified URI.  Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

```
        dcatModel = RDFDataMgr.loadModel(URI);

        dcatModel.setNsPrefix("dcat", "http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#");
        dcatModel.setNsPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
        dcatModel.setNsPrefix("dct", "http://purl.org/dc/terms/");
        String uri = "http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database";
        Resource dataSetResource = dcatModel.getResource(uri);

        String propString = "http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#distribution";
        //String propString = "dcat:distribution";
        Property searchProperty = dcatModel.createProperty(propString);
        StmtIterator i = dataSetResource.listProperties(searchProperty);
```

Comment: Setting prefixes does not enable shorthand notation.

Comment: That would probably be suitable as an answer.  Is shorthand notation possible in this manner?  For instance is there any setting that would make it possible to search by shorthand string?

Comment: There is API support for this but it is easy enough in Java with NS+"#property" (which is all it means in Turtle anyway).  Some people use unusual custom URIs scheme making this not a simple matter of adding and still maintain long compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting prefixes does not enable shorthand notation.